# Getting SQLite data into UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite, xcode4, uiwebview

I'm modifying a SDK tutorial that pulled from a very basic SQLite DB and displayed the data from one field in an UIImageView, and description in an UITextView.

My project requires that the TextView be changed to a WebView.

I'm pretty close, but my hangup is with these two lines of code–I think!

```
NSString *descData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[animal description]]];
[self.animalView.animalDesciption loadHTMLString:descData baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

Everything is working good (that is the app doesn't crash), except that nothing is displayed in the description/UIWebView!

I really don't know much about all of this stuff, and ANY help would be very appreciated!

Please let me know if I need to give any more info.

Comment: Please put the above in an answer and mark your question answered.

Comment: @Owen Hartnett I will as soon as I can, the system is saying that I have to wait several hours

Comment: @Jenox I will accept the answer, but the system says that I have to wait 21 hours! There is no SQL in the question because that was all working by pushing the data into a textView but not a webView.

Comment: Why is SQL in the title then? 'Getting SQLite data...'

Comment: @Jenox because I'm still learning how to explain what I'm wanting to do, I didn't realize until afterwards that the SQL doesn't really have much to do with my question (because the SQL data was already in the `[animal description]` variable)! I'm sorry for the confusion, I'll try not to make that mistake again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out! Here's what I did:

```
NSString *html = [animal description];
[self.animalView.animalDesciption loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```